# DELETE rows in BigQuery table with SQL query that includes FOR statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to delete these rows:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `project.dataset.table` FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP("2022-08-30 11:10:00 UTC")
WHERE
  country = "US"
  AND SUBSTRING(request_start_date, 0,4) != CAST(year AS string)
```

The above query runs fine and returns the rows I want to delete. However, when I try to run:

```
DELETE
FROM
  `project.dataset.table` FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP("2022-08-30 11:10:00 UTC")
WHERE
  country = "US"
  AND SUBSTRING(request_start_date, 0,4) != CAST(year AS string)
```

I receive the following error:
`Syntax error: Unexpected keyword FOR at [3:55]`

I've tried various joins and merges with no luck. Any ideas?

EDIT:
My apologies - I left out a pretty important detail. The reason we need to use that FOR statement is because these rows were (incorrectly) modified. Therefore, that condition in the current version of the table will not return anything and thus just running:

```
DELETE
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
WHERE
  country = "US"
  AND SUBSTRING(request_start_date, 0,4) != CAST(year AS string)
```

Deletes 0 rows. I need to find which rows were modified in an earlier snapshot of the table, then delete those rows in the current table. Hoping this is actually possible

Comment: you can do `select` using time travel. to delete rows  - just remove time travel related part - `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP("2022-08-30 11:10:00 UTC")`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks. When I try and run that without the FOR statement, it removes 0 rows from the database

Comment: which means that those rows are not in the table anymore - so nothing to delete - as they already where deleted somewhen in between `TIMESTAMP("2022-08-30 11:10:00 UTC")` and now

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant. You're absolutely right. I left out some important context. Please see updated post. Hopefully that is clarifying

Comment: Is there an `ID` column which you can use on snapshot table to fetch the IDs of modified rows and then delete them in current version ?

Comment: As the comment from kaysush, is there an ID that you could use on a snapshot table?